# Javascript Thread Safe

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I have a buffer:

```
websocketbuffer = []
```

Client event from html:

```
<button type="button" onclick="buttonClicked()"></button>
<script>
    function buttonClicked() {
    // add some data to websocketbuffer
}
</script>
```

Websocket receive event:

```
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
    // update some data inside websocketbuffer
}
```

The task:

```
websocket.onopen = function (event) {
    setInterval(wsRun, 1000);
};
function wsRun() {
    // delete or update some data inside websocketbuffer
}
```

As you can see above, there is access to the same buffer from 3 different places. In such a case, can another function run before one function completely finish his job on `websocketbuffer`?
How should I design the software in such a situation?

EDIT:
Actually, what I want to ask is during the for loop(`websocketbuffer`) in one function, Can the other function change this array?

```
function wsRun() {
    for ( let i = 0; i < websocketbuffer.length; i++ ) {
        //lets say i = 0
        websocketbuffer[0] = ... //Update array
        //User has clicked to button and In this point Does buttonClicked() function invoke or some data comes from websocket Does ws.onmessage function runs ? or waits to finish wsRun function?
        //Is this possible?
    }
}
```

Comment: Javascript, at least in browsers, is single threaded unless you use background workers.

Comment: The link above should answer the use-case you edited into your question as well. The answer is no, that is not possible in your case. Your loop will _always_ run to completion before the next event is processed.